# Duplicate inserts when using QueryHints.BATCH

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm developing a Java desktop application (SE, JDK 1.6.0) connecting directly to a remote MySQL Server (5.0) via EclipseLink 2.3.0, using a Swing GUI.

The application where my problem occurs looks like this: the user issues a search for companies (e.g. all companies located in X) and the results are loaded in a `JTable`. When a user selects a company much additional data from other related tables is shown (e.g. notes about the company, employees, phone number of employees etc.), most of them are `@OneToMany` relations.

Because of the amount of data and tables needed for each entry I have to optimize my search query to use joins and batch fetch:

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.QueryHints;
import javax.persistence.Query;

Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Company c WHERE c.y = x");
query.setHint(QueryHints.LEFT_FETCH, "c.companyWebsiteCollection");
query.setHint(​QueryHints.BATCH, "c.person2companyRelationCollection");
List list = query.getResultList();
```

The problems occur with `person2companyRelationCollection` which holds relations to persons who have relations to other companies which have connections to other persons and companies etc.

When I select company1 in jTable1 and all related persons are shown in table2, an INSERT query is issued that tries to insert the shown `person2CompanyRelation` entity again into the DB, causing a `om.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry`.

What am I doing wrong with my query hints?

**Additional information**:

- I don't detach any objects
- I don't merge any objects
- all entities are managed by the same `EntityManager`
- all is done within the same transaction
- the PK of Person2companyRelation is a *composite primary key* (`@EmbeddedId`) containing

  1. `companyId`
  2. `personId`
  3. `relationTypeId`
- the problem doesn't occur when only using with `query.setHint(​QueryHints.LEFT_FETCH)`
- **Correction:** the problem does occur when batch-fetching any object using `QueryHints.BATCH`, regardless of the key type

Answer (score 0):

Are you detaching objects, mixing objects from different queries/transaction/entity managers, are you using merge?

Does the insert occur without using batch fetch?

How is the Id of the object and the relationship mapped?

Comment: I've added more information to the question. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: I tried to recreate the issue, and could not.  It may have something to do with the composite primary key, can you try batch fetching other relationships.  Please include the code for the classes and your query, transaction commit code.

Comment: Could you remove the JOIN_FETCH from the query, there may be an issue using both JOIN_FETCH and BATCH together in the same query.

Comment: I've removed all the Joins from the query but it doesn't help.

Comment: You're probably right: the problem seems related with _composite primary keys_ – but I can't restructure the DB at this point. I'll try generating a minimized compilable example reproducing the error so I can give you code.